# Optimizing query with tons of ".. OR COLUMN LIKE 'STRING%' OR ..."

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I usually reach out for StackOverflow when I'm in a deep state of desperation... so... any idea or insight about optimization will be very appreciated...

**Problem**: I have some queries where, in the where clause, I have something like this:

```
    WHERE VERSION = 462
        AND (CSB_CART_MAN LIKE '12010%'
        OR CSB_CART_MAN LIKE '12011%'
        OR CSB_CART_MAN LIKE '12013%'
    .
    .
    . )
and around a thousound conditions like the ones above.
```

- CSB_CART_MAN is a VARCHAR2.
- Data size - 160 rows with 51 columns.

As expected this is super slow...

Any ideas on how to optimize a situation like this? (a thousand "OR LIKE 'XXX%'")

**Data example:**

> ```
> CSB_CART_MAN - 270090
> CSB_CART_MAN - 2700910
> CSB_CART_MAN - 13911
> CSB_CART_MAN - 13912
> CSB_CART_MAN - 139130
> ```

What are these numbers?
- These numbers represent the IAS also known as "international accounting estimates"

Comment: Example of data in column CSB_CART_MAN

Comment: Are all patterns exactly five characters followed by an ampersand?

Comment: Do all these queries you mention contain the same fixed list of patterns?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it´s applicable to use regexp_like instead of standard-like?
Your sample above could be written as:

```
... WHERE regexp_like(CSB_CART_MAN, '^1201[0,1,3]')
```

btw.: my favorite place to form a regexp-pattern and test it is https://regex101.com/

... and with your newly supplied data-sample:

```
 WITH d AS (
   SELECT 270090 CSB_CART_MAN FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2700910 CSB_CART_MAN FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 13911 CSB_CART_MAN FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 13912 CSB_CART_MAN FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 139130 CSB_CART_MAN FROM dual 
   )
SELECT * 
  FROM d
 WHERE regexp_like(d.csb_cart_man, '^(2700|1391)\d{1,3}$')
```

which mean, value must start (^) with either "2700" or "1391", followed by 1 up to 3 digits and then reached the end ($)

Answer (score 0):

I would look at putting the search strings into a table (possibly a temporary table) and `JOIN`ing to that instead:

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    My_Table MT
INNER JOIN Search_Criteria SC ON MT.CSB_CART_MAN LIKE SC.string_pattern
WHERE
    version = 462
```

Comment: we are going to try something similiar to your approach. I think the temporary table could be a good idea in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You want performance wise query then you must be filter first 4 digit to data and join this table to main table and again filter whatever you want

like this

```
SELECT
    MT.*
FROM
    My_Table MT
INNER JOIN(
         select * from my_table 
         where  version = 462
         cSB_CART_MAN LIKE '1201%')a
 ON a.id=mt.id
WHERE
(a.CSB_CART_MAN LIKE '12010%'
        OR a.CSB_CART_MAN LIKE '12011%'
        OR a.CSB_CART_MAN LIKE '12013%'
    .
    .
    . )
```

Comment: I wonder why join? Will `where  version = 462 and (cSB_CART_MAN LIKE '1201%') and
(a.CSB_CART_MAN LIKE '12010%'
        OR a.CSB_CART_MAN LIKE '12011%'
        OR a.CSB_CART_MAN LIKE '12013%' ..)` get a good plan too?

Comment: @Serg join is used to filtered data on this table and then to apply where condition to getting result of joining.

Answer (score 0):

With around a thousand `OR` conditions, it wouldn't make much sense for the DBMS to use an index. The table must be read record by record and compared with the list. So me must get the comparision itself fast.

You are using `LIKE` which is a pattern matching operator. You give it a pattern, e.g. '12010%' that must be parsed for wildchars ('%' and '_'). It would be possible to look for something complicated like '1_2%345%', so it must have a rather sophisticated algorithm to do that. It is hence probably much better to make an explicit comparision without wildchars:

```
substr(csb_cart_man, 1, 5)  = '12010'
```

I was taught that using a function such as `substr` on a column makes it impossible for the optimizer to use an index, whereas it might use an index on `like 'xxx%'. That sounds kind of strange to me. If the optimizer is able to examine 'xxx%' on whether it starts with non-wildcard characters, why can't it see the 1 in`substr(col, 1, n)`? But anyhow, as mentioned it makes no sense to use an index on your query anyway, so no problem.

I would write the query thus:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where version = 462
and substr(csb_cart_man, 1, 5) in ('12010', '12011', '12013', ...);
```

respectively thus for multiple lengths:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where version = 462
and 
(
  substr(csb_cart_man, 1, 5) in ('12010', '12011', '12013', ...)
  or
  substr(csb_cart_man, 1, 6) in ('120444', '120555', '120777', ...)
);
```

With one fixed length you could try with a function index, but as mentioned, I don't think it will be used:

```
create index idx_fivechars on mytable( version , substr(csb_cart_man, 1, 5) );
```

Comment: Thanks my friend. I think the substr approach could be a very good solution. We are going to try this solution. I'll get back to you as soon as possible. P.S: I can't upvote you. Not enough reputation points.

Comment: Don't worry about points. Hope my query helps. You should always answer the questions in the comments section to your request, though, in order to make it easier for us to help.

Comment: Got it! Thank you.